# Manipulating a file that is like XML

Tags: c#, .net, file-manipulation

I have a file that I want to read and manipulate.  It is XML like but is not an actual XML file.  It does reference a DTD however.  What part of the .Net framework can I use to do the above?  Will the XML API's work some how with this file?

Comment: Can you clarify how your file differs from XML?

Comment: It does not have the suffix XML for the file name, mabye this is not important anyway. It does not define an XML tag at the start e.g. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. It does however, have a tag referencing the dtd document e.g. <!DOCTYPE ARCXML SYSTEM "\\fooServer\ArcIMS\DTD\ArcXml.dtd">

Comment: If that is all that is "wrong" most parsers will handle missing XML headers gracefully. The key is to know if the XML inside the document is well formed (the fact that is references at DTD is promising). I would frankly just try feeding the parser and if it chokes perhaps run a pre-processing step to make the document well formed (assuming things like implied end tags or other "regular" non-xml issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply to my comments, it sounds like if all that is different from a standard XML document is the lack of a  header, the tools should work perfectly fine with that data. I would give System.Xml a try, and if that doesn't work, try prepending the header.